# import folder/* equivalent for Sass in 2022

Tags: sass, gulp

I've used [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) to import all sass-files from a folder via something like `@import "folder/*.scss";`. But node-sass is old and the `@import` statement is being phased out of Sass.

The new way of importing files is the `@use` statement. But it doesn't support wildcards at all. You cannot do `@use "article/*.scss"`

However, `@use` doesn't handle wildcards. So the current concept is that you have to mention every single file that you want to use.

Via `@use "article/header.scss", "article/footer.scss", "article/image.scss"`

Another common option is having a type of index-file such as `article/index.scss` that contains the code `@forward "article/header.scss", "article/footer.scss", "article/image.scss"` and is 'imported' to other files via `@use "article/index.scss"`

I really dislike the idea of having to manually write down all files within a folder, instead of just importing `folder/*`. I guess wildcard imports have been discouraged due to the assumption that import-order is crucial. In my case though, it's not, all my sass-files use very specific selectors meaning import-order doesn't matter, and I'm only annoyed by having to manually reference all files in a folder instead of being able to reference `folder/*`

### Is there any modern (updated 2020 or later) plugin to resolve this

We use plain sass and gulp.

So a gulp-plugin would be an option.

The most recent globbing plugin I've found is https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass-glob but the last release was 3 years ago, so the project still assumes you'd use the `@import` statement - unaware that it's deprecated. So I don't see that as a viable option.

If there's pre-made plugin I guess one option could be to use a custom build script to traverse all our sass-folders and generate index-files.